# Как правильно сделать подписку на фильтр?

Tags: laravel, архитектура, поиск, elasticsearch, фильтр

Задача сделать подписку на фильтр, но не очень понятно как проектировать правильно структуру такого функционала.

Поиск работает на основе ElasticSearch. Сами исходные данные храним в PostgreSQL. Приложение написано на Laravel.

Возникает несколько вопросов:

- Как и где хранить сам фильтр? часть запроса строиться по общим
  фильтрам а часть по динамическим фильтрам (придётся наверное хранить
  в формате json)
- Когда появляется новое объявление, что приложение
  должно сделать? Как оно узнает кто именно подписался на данное
  конкретное объявление? (не взять же все подписки по очереди и
  проверять каждую)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации этого отлично подходят [percolate запросы](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html).

Если обычно вы добавляете в индекс документы, а потом при поиске используете фильтр и в результате получаете документы, которые попадают под фильтр. В percolate запросах все наоборот, вы добавляете в индекс фильтры. А потом при поиске задаете документ и вам возвращаются фильтры, которые совпадают с этим документом, т.е. если их применить в обычном поиске, то документ будет найден.

Так вот, вы можете для каждой подписки создать фильтр (или использовать существующий), сохранить его в виде json в БД и ассоциировать его с подпиской, так чтоб можно было по фильтру найти подписку, а значит и пользователя. Далее нужно зарегистрировать фильтр как percolate запрос в elasticsearch.

Объявления будут документами. Теперь, когда появляется новое объявление делаете percolate запрос и он возвращает фильтры, которые совпадают с объявлением. Результат запроса возвращается в виде json фильтра. Теперь по нему в БД ищете подписки и пользователей, которые их создали.

Comment: примерно как тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111326/8618607 ?